# About PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

If I create an HTML/CSS/JS mobile app that targets an iPhone, does PhoneGap Build take my app and create it for the other platforms/devices?

Should my app be developed to handle the different screen sizes or will PhoneGap Build do that for me?

Comment: You can make use of various Mobile UI framework(e.g Jquery Mobile, Ionic, Dojo Mobile, Kendo UI, Sencha touch etc.) to take care of various screen sizes for your app OR you can employ **Resposive Web Design** ( RWD) for your app.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. It's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You have to manage different screen sizes. PhoneGap/cordova will only provide a wrapper around your web pages which can be deployed on mobile device. it will not change anything in your constructed pages.

for example: for iOS build it will create wrapper in Objective-c and create output file as 'ipa'. and for android it will create wrapper in android and create output file as 'apk'